# Weird crash when destructor of an STL vector is called

Tags: c++, stl, mingw

I have a program that gets some data from a mysql database, calls a function to process that data, and exits. I'm getting a weird error when running it...the program crashes when the function returns a value. As I suspected it's a problem with the destructor of one of my classes. The class holds two vectors (one of doubles, the other of a date class I wrote myself). The program crashes when the vector of doubles is destroyed.

Manually erasing the vector in the destructor doesn't do anything.

When I call the destructor manually I don't get this error. It only happens when I return a value from my function. Going line-by-line the crash happens in stl_vector.h on the line

`{ _M_deallocate(this->_M_impl._M_start, this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage - this->_M_impl._M_start); }`

Googling hasn't been very helpful...I found that assigning a value outside the size of the vector might trigger something like this but I've gone through my code and ensured that that doesn't happen.

The error:

```
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
In ntdll!DbgUiConnectToDbg () (C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll)
```

The call stack:

```
#0 7C90120F ntdll!DbgUiConnectToDbg() (C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll:??)
#1 7C96EE31 ntdll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey() (C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll:??)
#2 7C96F26E ntdll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey() (C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll:??)
#3 7C970456 ntdll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey() (C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll:??)
#4 7C94BAFC ntdll!LdrFindEntryForAddress() (C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll:??)
#5 00000000 0x006b0000 in ??() (??:??)
#6 00000000 0x50000061 in ??() (??:??)
#7 00000000 0x00f57008 in ??() (??:??)
#8 00000000 0x006b0000 in ??() (??:??)
#9 00000000 0x00f57008 in ??() (??:??)
#10 00000000    0x40000060 in ??() (??:??)
#11 00000000    0x00f60558 in ??() (??:??)
#12 00000000    0x002240b0 in ??() (??:??)
#13 00000000    0x00223804 in ??() (??:??)
#14 7C96F2D7    ntdll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey() (C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll:??)
#15 7C91A1BA    ntdll!RtlpUnWaitCriticalSection() (C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll:??)
#16 77C2C2DE    msvcrt!free() (C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll:??)
#17 00000000    0x006b0000 in ??() (??:??)
#18 00000000    0x00000000 in ??() (??:??)
```

Using MinGW in Code::Blocks on winxp. There's a ton of code and since I don't really know where it goes wrong I don't know what to include here...

Thanks for the help.

**Edit:**

A bunch of code that may or may not be relevant:

Fetching the data, initializing the dated_observations objects (the vectors in these are causing the crashes) and adding the data to them (note that from this point up until the function terminates, I only read values from these objects...no elements are added, modified, or deleted):

```
query_ss << "SELECT * FROM stock_data WHERE stock_id = " << stock1_id;
mysql_query(connect,query_ss.str().c_str());
query_ss.str("");
res_set = mysql_store_result(connect);
numrows = mysql_num_rows(res_set);

dated_observations s1_p(numrows);
dated_observations s1_r(numrows);

for(i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
    row = mysql_fetch_row(res_set);
    s1_p.my_insert(row[2], std::atof(row[3]));
    s1_r.my_insert(row[2], std::atof(row[4]));
}
```

The dated class:

```
#ifndef _DATED_H_
#define _DATED_H_

#include <vector>
#include "date.h"       // my date class

template <class T> class dated {
private:
    int counter;
public:
    vector<date> dates_;
    vector<T> elements_;
    //dated<T>();
    dated<T>(const int&);
    dated<T>(const dated<T>&);
    dated<T> operator= (const dated<T>&);
    ~dated() { clear(); };
    void clear();                     // erasing
    void insert(const date&, const T&); // insert somewhere
    void my_insert(const date&, const T&); // insert at the end

    bool empty() const ;
    int  size() const ;
    bool contains(const date& d) const ;
    date date_at(const int& t) const ; // accessing elements, here dates
    T element_at(const int& t) const ;  // index directly
    T element_at(const date& d) const ; // index indirectly, specify what date

    //date last_date() const ;
    //T last_element() const;

    // next: the element either on date d, if d is here, else the last observation before d.
    T current_element_at(const date& d) const ;

    vector<T> elements() const; // all elements as vector<T>
    vector<date> dates() const;  // all dates as vector<date>

    date first_date() const;  // simple queries
    date last_date() const;
    T first_element() const;
    T last_element() const;

    void set_counter(int cnt);
    int get_counter() const;

    int index_of_date(const date& d) const; // when searching in the data,
    int index_of_last_date_before(const date& d) const; // these are useful functions
    int index_of_first_date_after(const date& d) const;

    int no_observations_between(const date&first, const date& last) const;

    void remove(const date&);         // removing one or more elements
    void remove_between_including_end_points(const date&, const date&);
    void remove_between(const date&, const date&);
    void remove_before(const date&);
    void remove_after(const date&);
};

#include "dated_main.h"
#include "dated_search.h"
#include "dated_remove.h"

template<class T> dated<T> observations_between(const dated<T>& obs,const date&first, const date& last);
template<class T> dated<T> observations_after(const dated<T>& obs, const date& first);
template<class T> dated<T> observations_before(const dated<T>& obs, const date& last);
template<class T> dated<T> end_of_year_observations(const dated<T>&);
template<class T> dated<T> beginning_of_month_observations(const dated<T>&);
template<class T> dated<T> end_of_month_observations(const dated<T>&);
template<class T> dated<T> observations_matching_dates(const dated<T>& obs, const vector<date>& dates);

#include "dated_util.h"
#endif
```

Some of the methods of the dated class:

```
//template<class T> dated<T>::dated(){;};   // not necessary to do anything,

template<class T>dated<T>::dated(const int& init_size = 0) {
    // for speed, initialize first with correct size and then copy
    counter = 0;
    if(init_size > 0) {
        dates_=vector<date>(init_size);
        elements_=vector<T>(init_size);
    }
};

template<class T>dated<T>::dated(const dated<T>& dobs) {
    // for speed, initialize first with correct size and then copy
    counter = 0;
    dates_=vector<date>(dobs.size());
    elements_=vector<T>(dobs.size());
    for (int t=0;t<dobs.size();++t){
        dates_[t]      = dobs.date_at(t);
        elements_[t]   = dobs.element_at(t);
    };
};

template<class T> dated<T> dated<T>::operator= (const dated<T>& dobs) {
    counter = 0;
    if (this==&dobs) return *this; // check against self assignment;
    clear();
    dates_=vector<date>(dobs.size());
    elements_=vector<T>(dobs.size());
    for (int t=0;t<dobs.size();++t){
        dates_[t]        = dobs.date_at(t);
        elements_[t]     = dobs.element_at(t);
    };
    return *this;
};

template<class T> dated<T>::~dated();

template<class T> bool dated<T>::empty() const { return (dates_.size()<1); };

template<class T> int  dated<T>::size() const { return dates_.size(); };

template<class T> date dated<T>::date_at(const int& t) const { // accessing with bounds checking
   if ( (t>=0) && (t<size()) ) return dates_[t];
   return date();
};

template<class T> T dated<T>::element_at(const int& t) const {  // accessing with bounds checking
   if ( (t>=0) && (t<size()) ) return elements_[t];
   return T();
};

template<class T> void dated<T>::set_counter(int cntr){
    counter = cntr;
}

template<class T> int dated<T>::get_counter() const {
    return counter;
}

template<class T> T dated<T>::element_at(const date& d) const {
   if (!contains(d)) return T();
   return elements_[index_of_date(d)];
};

template <class T> void dated<T>::my_insert(const date& d, const T& obs) {
    if (!d.valid()) return;
    elements_[counter] = obs;
    dates_[counter] = d;
    counter++;
};

template<class T> void dated<T>::clear() {
   dates_    .erase(dates_    .begin(),dates_    .end());
   elements_ .erase(elements_ .begin(),elements_ .end());
};
```

The dated_observations class:

```
#ifndef _DATED_OBS_H_
#define _DATED_OBS_H_

#include "dated.h"      // templated dated<> class
#include <string>     // ANSI string class

class dated_observations : public dated<double>{
   private:
      string         title_;
   public:
      dated_observations(const dated_observations& dobs); //copy constructor
      dated_observations(const int& init_size = 0) : dated<double>(init_size) {;}

      void clear();
      ~dated_observations() { clear(); };

      void set_title(string s); // title
      string title() const;

      int no_obs() const;
      int no_obs_between(const date& d1, const date& d2) const;
      int no_obs_before(const date& d) const;
      int no_obs_after(const date& d) const;
};

///// io
ostream& operator << (ostream&, const dated_observations& );
void print_dated_observations(ostream& of, const dated_observations& d, int precision=3);

//// mischellaneous utilities
double max_obs(dated_observations& dobs);
double min_obs(dated_observations& dobs);
bool dates_match(const dated_observations& obs1, const dated_observations& obs2);

///// picking subsets.
dated_observations observations_between(const dated_observations& obs,const date& first,const date& last);
dated_observations observations_after(const dated_observations& obs, const date& first);
dated_observations observations_before(const dated_observations& obs, const date& last);
dated_observations observations_matching_dates(const dated_observations& obs, const vector<date>& dates);

///// picking periodic elements
dated_observations beginning_of_month_observations(const dated_observations&);
dated_observations end_of_month_observations(const dated_observations&);
dated_observations end_of_year_observations(const dated_observations&);
dated_observations end_of_year_current_observations(const dated_observations&);

#endif
```

Some of the dated_observations methods:

```
dated_observations::dated_observations(const dated_observations& dobs) {
    elements_ = dobs.elements_;
    dates_ = dobs.dates_;
    set_counter(dobs.get_counter());
}

void dated_observations::set_title(string s) { title_ = s; };

void dated_observations::clear() {
   title_ = string();
   dated<double>::clear();
   set_counter(0);
};
```

**Another edit:**

Removing all the code between the initialization of s1_p & s1_r and the end actually removes the error. Could maybe trying to read or copy a value outside the size of the vector cause this?

Comment: The error is likely in the context of the delete, or in other part in the code, as it happens usually in these kind of errors because allocation/deallocation. Try to publish the code where you think the error might be introduced.

Comment: The error is in your code. You haven’t shown your code.

Comment: Maybe try running your app under the application verifier (google it).
Also, try writing a separate test app that can run the return of the value at the point of the crash so that you can be run this code in isolation to exclude the possibility of other areas of the program corrupting the heap.

Comment: If you comment out both `s1_p.my_insert` and `s1_r.my_insert` from the for loop, does it still crash on returning?

Comment: The application verifier did the trick, thanks. The issue was not checking the range of the search algorithm...not sure why it didn't throw an error on the spot and had to wait for the destructor to be called though.

Comment: @JohnSmith: So is the problem solved? If so, feel free to post an answer to your own question and accept it.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.